# CAML Query issue - OR and AND

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, caml-query

I'm working on an application that uses a CAML query to return certain documents based on a number of search and filter parameters. I need some assistance with a query that uses both AND and OR conditions.

The simplified version of the query I need to run is:

```
WHERE Created >= '2018-10-01'
AND Created <= '2018-10-24'
AND (File_Type == 'docx' || File_Type == 'xlsx' || File_Type == 'pptx')
AND (Title CONTAINS 'weekly' || Description CONTAINS 'weekly')
```

And the CAML Query I have created is:

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value Type="DateTime">2018-10-01 00:00:00</Value>
        </Geq>
        <And>
            <Leq>
                <FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value Type="DateTime">2018-10-24 00:00:00</Value>
            </Leq>
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name="File_x0020_Type" /><Value Type="Text">docx</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Or>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="File_x0020_Type" /><Value Type="Text">xlsx</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Or>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name="File_x0020_Type" /><Value Type="Text">pptx</Value>
                        </Eq>
                        <Or>
                            <Contains>
                                <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" /><Value Type="Text">weekly</Value>
                            </Contains>
                            <Contains>
                                <FieldRef Name="Description0" /><Value Type="Text">weekly</Value>
                            </Contains>
                        </Or>
                    </Or>
                </Or>
            </Or>
        </And>
    </And>
</Where>
```

When I run the query I get all results where either of the Title/Description or File_Type parameters are met.

My question is how do I rearrange the CAML query to incorporate an AND condition for both Title/Description and File_Type?

Comment: Try creating a query using CAML Designer (a free tool to create SharePoint caml queries)

Comment: @harshalgite Thanks for the suggestion, but are there any online tools similar to this? company policy prevents unauthorised downloads

Comment: You can try this one https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/caml-designer-2013-for-sharepoint/

Comment: You need to tell them you need this tool and get authorization for download. CAML is not most intuitive language to work with and CAML tools are essential for productivity as SP DEV.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, but I eventually worked it out through trial and error.

I had to seperate the two conditions into two OR threads nested inside an AND as such:

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name="Created" />
            <Value Type="DateTime">2018-01-01 00:00:00</Value>
        </Geq>
        <And>
            <Leq>
                <FieldRef Name="Created" />
                <Value Type="DateTime">2018-10-24 00:00:00</Value>
            </Leq>
            <And>
                <Or>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="File_x0020_Type" />
                        <Value Type="Text">xlsx</Value>
                    </Eq>
                    <Or>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name="File_x0020_Type" />
                            <Value Type="Text">docx</Value>
                        </Eq>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name="File_x0020_Type" />
                            <Value Type="Text">pptx</Value>
                        </Eq>
                    </Or>
                </Or>
                <Or>
                    <Contains>
                        <FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef" />
                        <Value Type="Text">weekly</Value>
                    </Contains>
                    <Contains>
                        <FieldRef Name="Description0" />
                        <Value Type="Text">weekly</Value>
                    </Contains>
                </Or>
            </And>
        </And>
    </And>
</Where>
```